# Firebase Authentication in Unity Rejects "Sign In With Apple" Tokens

Tags: ios, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase Unity. My app needs to support Sign In With Apple to be approved for the App Store.

The official firebase instructions require diving into native code. It would be non-trivial for me to implement this and write code to talk to Unity.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/apple

Unity has implemented an easy-to-use "Sign In With Apple" plugin
https://blogs.unity3d.com/2019/09/19/support-for-apple-sign-in/

Apple Sign In works at the Unity level until I try to use OAuth with Firebase. Signing in with this credential gets rejected:

```
OAuthProvider.GetCredential("apple.com", idToken, accessToken);
```

I have a good idea what the idToken is (Unity's `args.userInfo.idToken`), but the accessToken is unclear. I feel like I am so close. If I can get advice on what to search for next, I would be most grateful!

Answer (score 0):

You are reading wrong page!

The one with native code is when you directly implement for iOS. That's not what you are doing. You are implementing c# for Unity so you have to read the [Get Started](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup) and [API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity) for the Unity SDK!

---

**However**, what is actually ment by your app needs to provide login via Apple is **directly** via the Apple store! Unity has a dedicated [Asset](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/sign-in-with-apple-154202) for this!

Comment: Unfortunately, Firebase does not have an API page for "Sign In With Apple" implementation in C# with Unity. Without dedicated documentation, I got very far  using Unity's dedicated asset. The step I am stuck on is: once I log in on the game client, how do I pass the correct "idToken" and "accessToken" to Firebase Authentication?

Answer (score 0):

The release of Firebase 6.10.0 on January 30th 2020 enabled me to solve this issue!

[OAuthProvider.GetCredential()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/auth/o-auth-provider#summary) now has a method overload that takes a "nonce", which is required to complete the Sign In With Apple server verification.

I modified the popular [Apple Sign In Unity](https://github.com/lupidan/apple-signin-unity/) project to generate a "nonce" value and expose it to Unity code. At the time of this writing, there is an [active pull request](https://github.com/lupidan/apple-signin-unity/pull/16) with the (quick and dirty) implementation. It looks like the code will be refactored a good amount before it is merged into the main project.

With my modified Apple Sign In Unity project implemented, getting the credential is straightforward:

```
_appleAuthManager.LoginWithAppleId(
        LoginOptions.IncludeEmail | LoginOptions.IncludeFullName,
        (credential) =>
        {
            // success
            var appleIDCredential = credential as IAppleIDCredential;
            string authCode = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(appleIDCredential.AuthorizationCode);
            string idToken = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(appleIDCredential.IdentityToken);
            string rawNonce = _appleAuthManager.RawNonce;
            Credential credential = OAuthProvider.GetCredential("apple.com", idToken, rawNonce, authCode);
        },
        (error) =>
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Sign in with Apple failed: " + error.ToString());
        });
```